# Lua rough sort, then fine sort

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

Let's say I have this table in Lua:

```
items = {
    {7007, "quux", 9.7},
    {1004, "foo", 12.3},
    {1234, "bar", 9.6},
    {1234, "baz", 8.8},
}
```

And I sort in this way:

```
function compare(a,b)
  return a[1] < b[1]
end

table.sort(items, compare)
```

This would result in the table being sorted by the first item, but because 2 of the items have the value "1234," their positions relative to each other are arbitrary.

How would I go about doing a second sort of the table so that "1234" keep their absolute positions in the table, but use the third values (9.6 and 8.8) to perform a finer sort?

Answer (score 2):

You simply add more logic to your compare function. The return value of the compare function tells Lua which of both items comes first. If it returns true, a will come first, else b will come first.

```
function compare(a,b)
  if a[1] == b[1] then
    return a[3] < b[3]
  else
    return a[1] < b[1]
  end
end
```

Or shorter:

```
function compare(a,b)
  return a[1] < b[1] or a[1] == b[1] and a[3] < b[3]
end
```

This is pretty simple. Would you please follow my last advice on one of your very similar questions? Take pen an paper and write down how you would solve this in English or whatever your native language is.

Item a comes befor b if a[1] is smaller then b[1],
else, if a[1] equals b[1] then a comes first if a[3] is smaller then b[3].

If you translate this to Lua it looks like:

```
function compare(a, b)
  if a[1] < b[1] then
    return true
  elseif a[1] == b[1] then
    if a[3] < b[3] then
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

This also works but you can write it more compact as I have shown above.